# Cypher: variable length path with condition on each node

Tags: path, neo4j, cypher

If I want to find a path of varibale length in my graph from node `A` to node `B` where all nodes in between have a certain label, and `A` and `B` have a different label -- how would I do that?

`MATCH (A)-[*0..]->(B) WHERE ??`

Answer (score 4):

This query should work if all nodes have only a single label:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[*]->(b)
WITH p, LABELS(a) AS la, LABELS(b) AS lb, NODES(p)[1..-1] AS nodes
WITH p, la, lb, nodes, LABELS(nodes[0]) AS label
WHERE label <> la AND label <> lb AND ALL(x IN nodes[1..] WHERE LABELS(x) = label)
RETURN p;
```

The query requires all the middle nodes to have the same label, and the end nodes to have a different label (or labels) than the middle nodes.